# Using string inside ShareActionProvider share intent

Tags: android, android-intent, action, share, provider

I'm trying to get ShareActionProvider to work and I've run into the following problem:

This code works:

```
      Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text I want to share");

    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem.getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
```

But this doesn't:

```
      Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, webView.getUrl());

    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem.getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
```

Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure `getUrl()` is returning a valid value? And what does "doesn't" with respect to "works" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare I just figured it out myself, I was only calling mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent() when the menu was created, before the webview had loaded the page.

Comment: You could put the answer in the answer section and mark it as an answer, instead of the question remaining pending.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, webView.getUrl().toString());
```

instead of

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, webView.getUrl());
```